# How to verify 2 hashed values with different salts originating from the same clear-text password?

Tags: passwords, hash, salt

I have a project where I need to do an account merge across two websites.

Some percentage of users have accounts on both sites (same email address). Rather than just assume that two accounts with the same email address are the same identity, we'd like to go one step further and compare password hashes.

Both websites are on the same eCommerce platform, just 2 differently branded sites which we're consolidating into one. The hashing function is the same on both sites (SHA256) however we use different SALT's on each site.

For example:

**SITE#1**
password(1) = hello
salt(1) = abc123
hash(1) = 1a1A1a1A1a1A

**SITE2**
password(2) = hello
salt(2) = xyz456
hash(2) = 2b2B2b2B2b2B

Given just salt(1), hash(1), salt(2), hash(2), is it possible to verify that that password(1) and password(2) are the same? i.e I don't need to decrypt, just need to confirm that the two passwords are the same?

Comment: You can't, the question is, why would you?

Comment: Even if you _could_ check whether the passwords are the same (you can't), other than "because users are lazy" what makes you think they'd be using the same password on both sites?

Comment: You mention that you use different salts on each site. I hope that you mean that you use a random salt for every password. Having a single salt for an entire site is not appropriate password storage.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. That's kinda the point of a salt.

If you could tell two passwords with different salts were the same, then attacks using pre-computed hashes would still be possible, and salts would be pretty useless.

You would need the original password to verify both salted hashes are derived from the same password.

Answer (score 2):

The design of the system is that you cannot do this without knowing the original password.  The security goal is that you cannot test a password any faster than the hash.  If you can do an equivalency between the two faster than hashing, then you have a way to figure out the password faster than hashing it.

As an additional comment, I hope that the hashes are unique per user, not unique to the sites